# Acessing instance variables from a class results in "Use of undeclared variable foo"

Tags: objective-c

I want to access an instance variable from a class, but it doesn't seem to work:

ClassA.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA: NSObject

@property int foo;

-(int) foo;
-(void) setFoo: (int) f;

@end
```

ClassA.m:

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA
{
    int foo;
}

-(int) foo
{
    return foo;
}

-(void) setFoo: (int) f
{
    foo = f;
}

@end
```

CategoryA.h:

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ClassA (CategoryA)

-(void) print;

@end
```

CategoryA.m:

```
#import "CategoryA.h"

@implementation ClassA (CategoryA)

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"Foo: %i", foo); //Use of undeclared variable 'foo'; did you mean 'for'?
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "CategoryA.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] init];
        [a setFoo: 10];
        [a print];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly new to Objective-C so I might just have overlooked something.

I know I can just synthesize foo, but it results in the same error.

The project can be downloaded here: http://cl.ly/DL4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the variable declaration into the interface rather than putting it in the implementation:

```
@interface ClassA: NSObject {
    int foo;
}

@property int foo;

-(int) foo;
-(void) setFoo: (int) f;
```

Answer (score 2):

The category doesn't know that `foo` is an instance variable as you've defined it in the implementation of `ClassA`. You've declared it as a property but all that means is that there will be methods called `foo` and `setFoo:`, not that there is an instance variable called `foo` as well.

You should probably change `CategoryA` to this:

```
@implementation ClassA (CategoryA)

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"Foo: %i", self.foo);
}

@end
```